# Loop over an array to try multiple options on a page and come back to that initial page for each iteration

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to scrape some data from a site. On the main page, there is a dropdown with a list of all 50 states. The value is the 2 letter abbreviation.

```
var states;
casper.start(url);
casper.then(function() {
    states = this.evaluate(function getOptionVals() {
        // loop thru and get the values
        return arrayValues;
    });
});
```

Next I want to loop thru the array of abbreviations and then populate some elements on the same page. The page does not have a form on it, just some radio buttons and a submit button.

**The submit button navigates to a new .asp page passing in the search options as query string parameters.**

```
casper.then(function () {
    // loop over all states
    this.eachThen(states,function(state) {
        this.echo('state = ' + state.data);
        // step 1
        this.evaluate(function(state) {
            console.log('In .evaluate the state is '+state);
            // select the radio button
            $('#searchoption1').prop('checked',true);
            $('#searchoption2').prop('checked',false);
            $('#showall').prop('checked',true);
            // select the State from the dropdown
            $('#state option[value="'+state+'"]').prop('selected', true);
            $('#submit1').click();
        },state.data); // pass in the array from the first casper.then call
        // step 2
        this.waitForSelector('table.mainTable tbody table  tbody blockquote',function() {
            this.evaluate(function(){
                console.log($('table.mainTable h1 ').text());
            });
        });
    })
});
casper.run();
```

My problem is the asynchronous nature of CasperJS. When I run it the `console.log()` reports the results from the first state in the array for each pass thru the loop. I've tried a bunch of different approaches (from posts here on SO) for step 2, but to no avail.

How do I get the loop to wait until step 2 is complete before continuing?

**Here is what the output looks like:**

```
start step #1 get state abbreviations
start #2 loop over all states
state = AL
In .evaluate the state is AL
loc: (/Find_Range/wts_subresults_test.asp)
dir2: (e)
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = AK
In .evaluate the state is AK
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = AZ
In .evaluate the state is AZ
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = AR
In .evaluate the state is AR
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = CA
In .evaluate the state is CA
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = CO
In .evaluate the state is CO
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = CT
In .evaluate the state is CT
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
```

So the `this.waitForSelector` function with `this.evaluate` is not "finding" the right page in the browser context. I would expect the output to look like:

```
In .evaluate the state is AL
loc: (/Find_Range/wts_subresults_test.asp)
dir2: (e)
Ranges for the State/Province of Alabama
state = AK
In .evaluate the state is AK
Ranges for the State/Province of Alaska
state = AZ
In .evaluate the state is AZ
Ranges for the State/Province of Arizona
state = AR
In .evaluate the state is AR
Ranges for the State/Province of Arkansas
state = CA
In .evaluate the state is CA
Ranges for the State/Province of California
state = CO
In .evaluate the state is CO
Ranges for the State/Province of colorado
```

**So each pass through this.each should navigate back to the first page after step 2.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the submit button navigates to another page, but the issue seems to be that you're not on the initial page in the next iteration of `eachThen` anymore:

> So each pass through this.each should navigate back to the first page after step 2.

You have two options at this point:

#### 1. Open the page you were on at the beginning in every iteration:

```
casper.then(function () {
    var url = this.getCurrentUrl();
    // loop over all states
    this.eachThen(states, function(state) {
        this.echo('state = ' + state.data);
        // step 0
        this.thenOpen(url);
        // step 1
        this.thenEvaluate(...);
        // step 2
        this.waitForSelector(...);
    })
});
```

Note that I used `thenEvaluate` instead of `evaluate`, because a synchronous function call like `evaluate` should not follow an asynchronous step function call like `thenOpen`.

#### 2. Go back:

```
casper.then(function () {
    // loop over all states
    this.eachThen(states, function(state) {
        this.echo('state = ' + state.data);
        // step 1
        this.thenEvaluate(...);
        // step 2
        this.waitForSelector(...);
        // step 3
        this.back();
    })
});
```

Note that you might have to use `back` twice (or more): `this.back().back();`, because sometimes there are redirects and PhantomJS doesn't go to the pre-redirect page in a single step.

---

If you're navigating with CasperJS, then there is usually only one `page` instance. Additional page instances can be created when you click something and a new window/popup is created, but that's not what's happening here.

The reason you see a different short state name, but always the same long state name is because `states` is populated before you even begin iteration, but you continue to be on the same page after the first iteration.

You could have noticed a problem with your script earlier by listening to the ["page.error" event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) which would have shown you that some elements cannot be found (inside `evaluate` after the first iteration):

```
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg);
    // maybe make it a little fancier with the code from the PhantomJS equivalent
});
```

Additionally, you should take screenshots `casper.capture(filename);` at every interesting if you want to know what is going on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Now I see the error I was making by not using thenEvaluate the first time. (I had tried it in the waitForSelector callback.) I had also tried using the page.error event, but the page has a lot of js errors on it and they just confused the issue. (I don't control the page I'm scraping). Using this.capture was also a good suggestion. Obviously, I'm new to capturejs and I'm thankful for your suggestions. Thanks Artjom.